# Can a set of asymptotic density zero have infinite sum of reciprocals?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For each subset of real numbers $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ define
$$d(A)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\rm{card}(A) \cap [1,n]$$
to be its asymptotic density (if it exists).

Also consider the sum of reciprocals
$$s(A)=\sum\limits_{\alpha \in A}\frac{1}{\alpha}$$

Is it possible that $d(A)=0$ at the same time that  $s(A)=\infty$? Also, is it possible that $d(A)\gt 0$ at the same time that $s(A)\lt \infty $?

Comment: Is that what you meant, or should there be a $1/n$ inserted in the definition of $d(A)$? Assuming so: You say for _each_ $A$. But that limit need not exist for every $A$. Do you want to restrict attention to $A$ for which the limit exists, or do you want $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ or something in the definition of $d(A)$?

Comment: "For each subset of real numbers $A\subset \mathbb{N}$" so you're actually looking for natural numbers then

Comment: Please avoid titles of the form "How do I shot web".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revising the question to what I suspect was intended, and in any case to what it seems to me the question should have been: For $A\subset\mathbb N$ define the *upper density* $d^+(A)$ by $$d^+(A)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#(A\cap[1,\dots,n])}{n}$$and define the *lower density* $d^-(A)$ similarly, with $\liminf$ in place of $\limsup$. Define $s(A)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac1n$.

Then (i) there exists $A$ with $d^+(A)=0$ and $s(A)=\infty$, and (ii) if $d^-(A)>0$ then $s(A)=\infty$.

For (i): Let $I_n=[2^n,2^n+1,\dots,2^{n+1}-1]$. Choose $A$ so that $$\#(A\cap I_n)\sim \frac1n2^n.$$Since $1/n\to0$ it follows easily that $d^+(A)=0$; on the other hand it's clear that $$\sum_{j\in I_n}\frac1j\ge \frac cn,$$hence $s(A)=\infty$.

For (ii): Say $d^-(A)=2\delta>0$. Fix $N$. There exists an infinite set $E$ such that $$\#(A\cap[N,\dots,n])\ge\delta n\quad(n\in E).$$For $n\in E$ we have $$\sum_{j\in A\cap[N,\dots,n]}\frac1j\ge\frac1n\#(A\cap[N,\dots,n])\ge\delta.$$
Since $\sum_{j\in A,\,\, j\ge N}\frac1j\ge\delta$ for *every* $N$ it follows that $s(A)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the set of primes has asymptotic density zero, but
$$ \sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p} $$
is divergent. Mertens' theorem gives $\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{x}\approx \log\log x.$